# How to communicate with the alarm Sur-Gard System 1

Tags: c#, tcp, alarm

I need to develop a software that catch all alarm alerts from a Sur-Gard System 1.
For now I created this tcp listener en c# and works fine using my phone as a client but it does not stablish communication with the Sur-Gard, I pingued to the sur-gard IP and there is communication between them, and I'm sure that the port it's correct.
What I'm doing wrong?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Reconect:
        System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener server = null;
        try
        {
            Int32 port = 1025;

            server = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port); 

            server.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($@"Waiting for a connection... ");

                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ThreadProc, client);
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            server.Stop();
        }

        goto Reconect;
    }

    private static void ThreadProc(object obj)
    {
        var client = (TcpClient)obj;
        Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
        String cadena_obtenida = null;

        cadena_obtenida = null;

        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        int i;

        try
        {
            while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
            {
                cadena_obtenida = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                Console.WriteLine("Alerta recibida: {0}", cadena_obtenida);

                byte[] respuesta = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("El servidor ha recibido: " + cadena_obtenida + Environment.NewLine);

                stream.Write(respuesta, 0, respuesta.Length);
                stream.Flush();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        client.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You are backwards.  The device is the server/listener and you are the client.  You cannot start both a client and server with same IP and Port number.

Comment: But there's software that can get the events, How do they do it?

Comment: See the msdn examples.  The examples use socket class and you can replace socket with any class that inherits the socket like TCPListener or TCPClient. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples

Comment: I will see them. Thanks!! ^^